# IntelliJ showing extra name in the project structure

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.4. when I create a module or import a module it is adding extra details in the project details. The extra name appears in the artifact while creating a project from Spring boot Initializer.

[image]

I am using Gradle, in the Gradle the name are seems fine:

[image]

Comment: The yellow underlined names match the names in the Gradle screenshot. So I guess the problem is the names _before_ the yellow underlined names. Those are the names IntelliJ gets from the packages or classes, you can even see you made a typo (_paymanent_) and IntelliJ uses the correct name it's gotten from the generated class.

Comment: In IntelliJ you will see folder name as well as module name. It shows module name in the bracket.

Comment: While creating the project I made the module name and folder name same, but I don't know how this happened ?

Answer (score 1):

If the module name does not match the project name - the module name is displayed in the brackets. While the other name - is the name of the directory of the module root.